# IntelliJIdea plugin for uml design?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Does anyome know a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA which will design UML diagrams taking in consideration ALSO the hibernate/jpa annotations?

I do know that Ctrl+ShifAlt+U creates a data classed diagram but it does not show you one to many etc relations...

Please note that i have entities classes manually 'designed' from the DB and not automatically generated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/ij/

Comment: In the community edition i do not find any option to import java package or classes and generate diagram from them...Do you know the option/short cut?

Comment: UML is not supported in the CE: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Cristian, did you expect any other reply?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use IntelliJIdea plugin for uml design.

You can download from[1].

[1] http://www.visual-paradigm.com/downloads/vpsuite/VP_Suite_Linux.sh